# Empaquetar un proyecto R dentro de una aplicación (orientación)

Tags: r

Desarrollé un modelo que simula el comportamiento de un proceso de manufactura. El código está desarrollado completamente en R y se alimenta de archivos de texto plano (nada muy complejo, sólo 4 archivos con parámetros de diseño de los equipos, condiciones de los productos, restricciones, etc).
Me pidieron evaluar la opción de pasar esto a una aplicación, de forma que no vean el código y eventualmente desarrollar licencias para el uso de esta aplicación.
Estoy un poco perdido en esto pero mas que saber la solución (dado que no soy experto en estas materias) les agradecería que me orienten en:

1. ¿Qué tipo de profesional se encarga de esto?
2. ¿En qué lenguaje sería recomendable desarrollar esto?

Gracias

Comment: Preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, checa [ask]

Comment: Para que implementes tu aplicación puedes usar shiny. La cual te generará una aplicación web. Shiny es un complemento de R así que no se te hará muy difícil aprenderlo.

Comment: Si quieres hacer las cosas bien, te sugiero que revises las condiciones de licencia de R que usa GPL-2/3: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.es.html por si te permite o no hacer esto. Por otro lado, lo único parecido a una app, es lo que ya te mencionaron: shiny apps, que podrias eventualmente hostear en algún servicio en la nube. Sino cualquier lenguaje que permita crear interfaces gráficas y que pueda invocar a R (y que ya conozcas) alcanzaría.

Comment: Gracias a todos, me sugirieron lo siguiente: